# how transpose a table using two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

i need help to transpose a table but just using one column and replicate information from another column.

**UPDATE**

I have this query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_document MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2206 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;

CREATE TABLE ALL_DOCUMENT ( 
     ID NUMBER(19,0) DEFAULT SEQ_document.nextval  NOT NULL
    ,ART_DOC    VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,TYPE_DOC   VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
    ,DATE_DOC   TIMESTAMP(6)
    ,VALUE_DOC  NUMBER(19,6)
    ,TABLENAME_DOC  VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
);




INSERT INTO "MIBDES"."ALL_DOCUMENT" (ART_DOC, TYPE_DOC, DATE_DOC, VALUE_DOC, TABLENAME_DOC) VALUES ('A00', '35', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-04-30 13:49:24.330761000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '9,7599', 'table_1');
INSERT INTO "MIBDES"."ALL_DOCUMENT" (ART_DOC, TYPE_DOC, DATE_DOC, VALUE_DOC, TABLENAME_DOC) VALUES ('A00', '75', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-14 13:50:02.312782000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '13,6562', 'table_2');
INSERT INTO "MIBDES"."ALL_DOCUMENT" (ART_DOC, TYPE_DOC, DATE_DOC, VALUE_DOC, TABLENAME_DOC) VALUES ('A00', '35', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-03-4 13:50:02.312782000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '6,9978', 'table_2');
INSERT INTO "MIBDES"."ALL_DOCUMENT" (ART_DOC, TYPE_DOC, DATE_DOC, VALUE_DOC, TABLENAME_DOC) VALUES ('A00', '16', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-04-8 13:50:02.312782000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '4,7851', 'table_3');

commit;
```

The idea or requirement is get this:

[image]

And i don't have a clear idea how to make this transpose. Can somebody give me a hand?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Do the columns `table_1` and `table_2` display the same value in all rows?

The following subquery to use `CASE` expression and `MAX` function can get one row.
Then you can get your expected result by joining the row and ALL_DOCUMENT table.

```
SELECT ART_DOC,TYPE_DOC,DATE_DOC,"table_1","table_2"
  FROM ALL_DOCUMENT CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME_DOC='table_1' THEN VALUE_DOC END) AS "table_1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME_DOC='table_2' THEN VALUE_DOC END) AS "table_2"
   FROM ALL_DOCUMENT) T;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ad2c6e0ed7a3604e2c72807185d5461)

Comment: i update my question because there was an error, when i upload my questions. Can you take a look the modifications and help me gith this? Regards

Comment: My query for your updated question is different from above. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case of your updated question, the query is below:

```
SELECT ART_DOC,TYPE_DOC,
  MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME_DOC='table_1' THEN VALUE_DOC END) AS "table_1",
  MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME_DOC='table_2' THEN VALUE_DOC END) AS "table_2",
  MAX(CASE WHEN TABLENAME_DOC='table_3' THEN VALUE_DOC END) AS "table_3"
FROM ALL_DOCUMENT
GROUP BY ART_DOC,TYPE_DOC
ORDER BY "table_1","table_2","table_3";
```

You can get VALUE_DOCs of each TABLENAME_DOC using by `GROUP BY` clause and `MAX` function with `CASE` expression.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=386cb77d9e4395622ded4bf3e8bf4a9a)

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two methods for pivoting within Oracle's SQL :

1. Using **Conditional Aggregation** :

   While you can pivot the resulting columns as

   ```
   SELECT art_doc, type_doc,
          MAX(CASE WHEN tablename_doc = 'table_1' THEN value_doc END) AS "table_1",
          MAX(CASE WHEN tablename_doc = 'table_2' THEN value_doc END) AS "table_2",
          MAX(CASE WHEN tablename_doc = 'table_3' THEN value_doc END) AS "table_3"
     FROM all_document 
    GROUP BY art_doc, type_doc;
   ```

   this is the *static method*, you'd better prefering the *dynamic method* through creating a function returning value of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` such as

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Documents RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
     v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
     v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
     v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767); 
   BEGIN
     SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN tablename_doc = '''||tablename_doc||'''  THEN value_doc END) AS "'||tablename_doc||'"' , ',' )
             WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_REPLACE(tablename_doc,'[^0-9]') ) )
       INTO v_cols
       FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT tablename_doc
               FROM all_document
             );

     v_sql :=
     'SELECT art_doc , type_doc, '|| v_cols ||'
        FROM all_document
       GROUP BY art_doc , type_doc'; 

     OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
     RETURN v_recordset;
   END;
   /
   ```
2. Using **PIVOT** Clause :

   with *static method* ;

   ```
   SELECT art_doc , type_doc, 
          MAX("table_1") AS "table_1",
          MAX("table_2") AS "table_2",
          MAX("table_3") AS "table_3"
     FROM all_document
    PIVOT 
    (
     MAX(value_doc) FOR tablename_doc IN ('table_1' AS "table_1",'table_2' AS "table_2",'table_3' AS "table_3")
    )
    GROUP BY art_doc , type_doc;
   ```

   with *dynamic method* :

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Documents RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
     v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
     v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
     v_cols_1    VARCHAR2(32767); 
     v_cols_2    VARCHAR2(32767);  
   BEGIN
     SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX("'||tablename_doc||'") AS "'||tablename_doc||'"' , ',' )
             WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_REPLACE(tablename_doc,'[^0-9]') ) )
       INTO v_cols_1
       FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT tablename_doc
               FROM all_document
             );

     SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||tablename_doc||''' AS "'||tablename_doc||'"' , ',' )
             WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_REPLACE(tablename_doc,'[^0-9]') ) )
       INTO v_cols_2
       FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT tablename_doc
               FROM all_document
             );

     v_sql :=
     'SELECT art_doc , type_doc, '|| v_cols_1 ||'
        FROM all_document
       PIVOT 
       (
         MAX(value_doc) FOR tablename_doc IN ( '|| v_cols_2 ||' )
       )
        GROUP BY art_doc , type_doc'; 

     OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
     RETURN v_recordset;
   END;
   /
   ```

and then revoke from *SQL Developer*'s console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Get_Pivoted_Documents;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result ;
```

or from *PL/SQL Developer*'s *Test Window* :

```
begin
  -- Call the function
  :result := get_pivoted_documents;  --> yields Value of type <Cursor>
end;
```